# HSB vs HSL vs HSV

Tags: c++, colors, hsv, hsl, hsb

I am making a Color class as a part of a very basic graphics API in c++. So I decided to take a look at Microsoft's .NET framework and noticed that their Color class has functions for HSB.

Then I started a research to determine whether I should provide HSB, HSL or HSV or ALL of them in my class.

So, I have 3 questions on HSB, HSL, HSV:

1. Is HSB same as HSL?
2. If not, why isn't there an HSBL or even HSBLV?
3. I find many different methods of calculating these values, can someone show me the FASTEST ones?

Comment: HSV == HSB. HSL != HSB.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I was not able to find a decent comparison on these. That is why i posted this :)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

> Is HSB same as HSL?

No. HSB is the same as HSV, but HSL is different. All these are used as a friendly way to represent RGB colors. The Wikipedia article on HSL and HSV explains the differences using color cylinders: [HSL and HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).

Basically, Hue is the same for HSB and HSL but the Saturation takes different values, and Brightness and Lightness are also different.

> If not, why isn't there an HSBL or even HSBLV?

I don't get the point. Both HSB/HSV and HSL can represent any RGB color. Having B and L independently is not possible because of the way they are defined. A given HSB Brightness and Saturation is associated to a fixed Lightness. In fact converting between them is very easy.

> I find many different methods of calculating these values, can someone show me the FASTEST ones?

There's a similar question here for calculating HSB from RGB: [Fast, optimized and accurate RGB <-> HSB conversion code in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614792/fast-optimized-and-accurate-rgb-hsb-conversion-code-in-c). There's a [Java implementation there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6614896/79125) that might help. For converting between HSB/HSV and HSL see [HSL vs HSB vs HSV](https://web.archive.org/web/20170321223122/http://codeitdown.com/hsl-hsb-hsv-color/).

Comment: Although this is a very old question, thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Links are outdated, (see HSL vs HSB vs HSV)

Comment: "Both HSB/HSV and HSL can represent any RGB color." Is the reverse true, too?

Comment: http://colorizer.org/
I want to add this reference for easy visualization

Answer (score 13):

HSB and HSV are the same, but **HSL** is different.

- HSB stands for Hue, Saturation, Brightness.
- HSV stands for Hue, Saturation, Value.
- HSL stands for Hue, Saturation, Light.

Here is a visual difference [from wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hsl-hsv_models_b.svg):
[image: hsl v hsv comparison showing multiple colour graphs]

Answer (score 12):

Originally the difference between Brightness And Lightness  Is. "Brightness" is used for Subtractive colors and "Lightness" for Additive colors. Now if your program is dealing with Subtractive colors like the CMYK system it is better to use HSB otherwise it is better HSL.

Answer (score 10):

1. HSB!=HSL and HSB==HSV
2. HSBL and HSBLV not exists because **L**ightness and **B**rightness (also called **V**alue) are substitutes
3. Here are conversion methods (more on wiki [HSL2RGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#HSL_to_RGB_alternative) and [HSV2RGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#HSV_to_RGB_alternative))

**HSV -> RGB** (implementation in js [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242144/javascript-convert-hsb-hsv-color-to-rgb-accurately/54024653#54024653))

[image]

**RGB -> HSV** (implementation in js [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022885/rgb-to-hsv-color-in-javascript/54070620#54070620))

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing UI it makes more sense to use HSL rather than HSV as you need to control the brightness (L) value of your color palette.

Comment: Its a matter of preference. A color space has 3 axes, so two controls are needed for either color representation. Your HSL description sounds like an HS color circle plus an L slider. HSV is traditionally done with an HV rectangle plus an S slider. Either way works.