# Javascript algorithm/function to generate RGB values for a color along the visible light spectrum

Tags: javascript, algorithm, colors

I'm looking for a Javascript function/algorithm that will generate an RGB value for a color that's p% along the "visible light" spectrum.

For example - given the visible light spectrum...

[image]

... and given p=0, the function should return the RGB of red (0% across this spectrum. Given p=50, the function should approximately return the RBG of green (50% across the spectrum). Finally, given p=100, the function would return the RBG of violet.

The function doesn't need to be technically/scientifically precise - I'm just looking for a reasonably close approximation, with reasonable sensitivity. (E.g., the RGB for p=76 should be different than for p=77).

Ideally, I'm looking for a pure math formula. I.e., I'd like to avoid actually loading the image below onto a Canvas, than using context.getImageData to find the color of a pixel p% across the image.

Of course, I have no idea if that's possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `HSVtoRGB` function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242144/javascript-convert-hsb-hsv-color-to-rgb-accurately) to create something easily.

```js
function HSVtoRGB(h, s, v) {
    var r, g, b, i, f, p, q, t;
    if (arguments.length === 1) {
        s = h.s, v = h.v, h = h.h;
    }
    i = Math.floor(h * 6);
    f = h * 6 - i;
    p = v * (1 - s);
    q = v * (1 - f * s);
    t = v * (1 - (1 - f) * s);
    switch (i % 6) {
        case 0: r = v, g = t, b = p; break;
        case 1: r = q, g = v, b = p; break;
        case 2: r = p, g = v, b = t; break;
        case 3: r = p, g = q, b = v; break;
        case 4: r = t, g = p, b = v; break;
        case 5: r = v, g = p, b = q; break;
    }
    return {
        r: Math.round(r * 255),
        g: Math.round(g * 255),
        b: Math.round(b * 255)
    };
}

function rainbow(p) {
    var rgb = HSVtoRGB(p/100.0*0.85, 1.0, 1.0);
    return 'rgb('+rgb.r+','+rgb.g+','+rgb.b+')';
}

for(var i=0; i<100; i++) {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.style.backgroundColor = span.style.color = rainbow(i);
    span.textContent = 'i';
    document.body.appendChild(span);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lib https://github.com/moagrius/Color to set a color and change hue (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue).

**Example:**

```
var color = new Color('#FF0000'); // red
color.hue(150);
color.getRGB(); // rgb(0, 255, 128) cerulean
color.hue(300);
color.getRGB(); // rgb(255, 0, 255) violet
color.hue(0);
color.getRGB(); // rgb(255, 0, 0) red
```

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally, I'm looking for a pure math formula. I.e., I'd like to avoid
>   actually loading the image below onto a Canvas, than using
>   context.getImageData to find the color of a pixel p% across the image.

The **visible light spectrum** can't be put into a formula, because which color we see at a specific wavelength doesn't follow a mathematical term. The human eye and brain are much too complicated for that!

Yes, you can display every color using a red, green and blue light bulb like a PC screen. But that doesn't mean that yellow, cyan and magenta divide the light spectrum into accurate thirds! In computer science, however, this is easily assumed to be true.

[image: Computer screen at a closer look]

This makes it easy to calculate on the colors:

```
Color       hue [°]     r  g  b     hex
------------------------------------------
red         0           1  0  0     FF0000
yellow      60          1  1  0     FFFF00
green       120         0  1  0     00FF00
cyan        180         0  1  1     00FFFF
blue        240         0  0  1     0000FF
magenta     300         1  0  1     FF00FF
```

You can display the colors on a wheel: the left on is the one a programmer would prefer, the right one is more like a visible light spectrum:

[image]

Now you can easily see why the rgb value can't be calculated if you want to use the *visible light spectrum*: It doesn't follow any rule. Apart from that, there isn't just one visible light spectrum: [Google it](https://www.google.de/search?q=visible%20light%20spectrum&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIss_56fPKAhWMK5oKHd5XAnQQ_AUIBygB&biw=1570&bih=735), you'll see that every image is slightly different.

---

I'd like to know what's the **specific reason** for getting the rgb value of a specific light wavelength: You can instead use the hue as the [other answers suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32471000/3393058), but be aware that the hue has different proportions than the visible light spectrum.

If real proportions are important, you will have to load an image into a canvas (an image height of 1 pixel would be enough ;) ) or you can store all the values in a JSON array.

Comment: I've checked and the pixels on my monitor horizontally and vertically straight. The one you posted only vertically straight. Horizontally, they're one up, one down. Why is that?

Comment: There are many different types of LCD screens (Liquid Crystal Display), and the one of my image is *not the most common one*. The pixels on most screens are arranged in straight rows and columns, like on your screen. I am sorry for confusing you with this image.

Comment: No, not really. I was more curious to know if this particular arrangement has any advantages. I'd like to read it about it if it has a name or still in production.