# Converting HSV to RGB is not working Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert HSV to RGB with Javascript.

For some reason, the output is not correct. The numbers returned are crazy. For instance, when passing in `hsv(0, 100, 100)` to the function, it returns `rgb(25500, -2524500, -2524500);`

That is obviously not a valid RGB value.

Here is the function that converts HSV to RGB :

```
function HSVtoRGB(h, s, v) {
    var r, g, b, i, f, p, q, t;
    if (arguments.length === 1) {
        s = h.s, v = h.v, h = h.h;
    }
    i = Math.floor(h * 6);
    f = h * 6 - i;
    p = v * (1 - s);
    q = v * (1 - f * s);
    t = v * (1 - (1 - f) * s);
    switch (i % 6) {
        case 0: r = v, g = t, b = p; break;
        case 1: r = q, g = v, b = p; break;
        case 2: r = p, g = v, b = t; break;
        case 3: r = p, g = q, b = v; break;
        case 4: r = t, g = p, b = v; break;
        case 5: r = v, g = p, b = q; break;
    }
    return {
        r: Math.round(r * 255),
        g: Math.round(g * 255),
        b: Math.round(b * 255)
    };
}
```

Comment: short code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54024653/860099

Answer (score 3):

Turns out, the function works properly.
The issue was with the values I was passing in.

Instead of `hsv(50, 100, 100)`, use `hsv(50/360, 1, 1)`.

You must divide the hue by 360, and the S and V are up to 1, not 100.