# How to get rgb code from color picker

Tags: jquery, html, color-picker

I am using a color picker spectrum. It workes fine if i pick the color from the available boxes panel and return the color in rgb format that's fine but when I pick the color random from the spectrum box it returns color's value in hsv. What I need is to get rgb color format on box.If user select from the default color box or from spectrum value should comes in rgb.[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript convert HSB/HSV color to RGB accurately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242144/javascript-convert-hsb-hsv-color-to-rgb-accurately)

Comment: "a color picker spectrum"... could you be more specific?

Comment: I am using $(".colorpicker").spectrum({
        showPalette: true,
        hideAfterPaletteSelect: true,
        palette: demoPalette,
    });        for colorpicker spectrum.

Comment: I am using it from limitless template so It might be a bootstarp.