# UIColor saturation brightness values different from the regular saturation luminosity values of a color

Tags: ios, uicolor, color-space

Why are UIColor hsb values different from the regular hsl values of a color?

For example the color brown is hue: 0, saturation: 59%, luminosity: 41%, but the UIColor values are hue: 0, saturation: 74%, brightness: 65%

The hue is the same, but the saturation and brightness values differ. I need to use hsb initializer of UIColor for my project. Is there a conversion algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things are going on here.

First, HSB == HSV, as [discussed in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668623/hsb-vs-hsl-vs-hsv).

Next, the HSB(V) color space and HSL color space are two different beasts. The following image  can help visualize it & shows the values you are getting:
[image]

As to how to convert them:

[image]