# Why does SASS Saturation color function results in different value from Mac color picker?

Tags: macos, function, sass, colors, color-picker

I'm using SASS HSL color functions to get individual values from HEX color. At the same time I'm entering the same HEX value into Mac color picker. But the resulting **saturation** value from SASS color function and Mac color picker are different. Why is that?

Here's the SASS code with the results:
[image]

```
$color: #3e8fcb;
@debug $color;
@debug 'Hue' round( hue($color) );
@debug "Sat" round( saturation($color) );
@debug "Lht" round( lightness($color) );
```

And here's the Mac color picker:
[image]

As you can see the's the difference in **saturation**:

- SASS: 58%
- Mac color picker: 69%

Why?

Answer (score 1):

That's because SASS color functions use **HSL** color model, while Mac color picker uses **HSB** (same as HSV) color model. In HSB and HSL the Hue is the same, but **Saturation takes a different value**.

Explained in this answer:
[HSB vs HSL vs HSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668623/hsb-vs-hsl-vs-hsv)

And in Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV